# When I put the Static IP I lose internet connection

Tags: ip, internet-connection, ipv4, cisco-vpn-client

I'm facing a problem we have several places that work by vpn from cisco and I can ping from this place to another with my static IP but I lose the internet connection and  when i put the automatic DHCP back in it keeps working but I can't ping the remaining machines, the others locals all have VPN and can ping to other machines and always have an internet connection even with static IP, I would like to know what I can do to solve this problem, I know that my gateway is right the ipv4 is free the submask is always the same and the dns I use what the internet provider provides

I would really appreciate if you could help me

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Can you reach other hosts on your LAN? What does your route table show?

Comment: I can ping inside my network outside of it, I just can't access the internet but only when I have the static IP configured

Comment: This is missing some vital information - such as the IP addresses/ranges for each setup.

Comment: Basically we have several "companies" all with cisco that promote VPN so that we can all be interconnected in the network with static IP defined as gateway type 10.0.0.1 and so on what happens is the computer that I am doing the tests is directly connected to cisco and I can communicate with the other machines outside and inside the place the issue is that I have no internet connection